# Should I have to add password_digest column in my students table to make student.authenticate(password) run ? Even if I am using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, jwt, token

I am implementing a Token-based Authentication API in my code following the steps of the link below:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api

authentication_controller.rb is:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :authenticate_request
 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

 def authenticate
  binding.pry
   command = AuthenticateStudent.call(params[:corporative_email], params[:password])

   if command.success?
     render json: { auth_token: command.result }
   else
     render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized
   end
 end
end
```

authenticate_student.rb is:

```
class AuthenticateStudent
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(corporative_email, password)
    binding.pry
    @corporative_email = corporative_email
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    binding.pry
    JsonWebToken.encode(student_id: student.id) if student
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :corporative_email, :password

  def student
    binding.pry
    student = Student.find_by_corporative_email(corporative_email)
    return student if student && student.authenticate(password)

    errors.add :student_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end
end
```

Everything goes fine until the last pry where the code breaks at `student.authenticate(password)` and server returns "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
". At console "password" returns "123456" as expected which means to me that given argument number should 1 not zero.

Does anybody know whats happening here ?

Comment: I have added the column password_digest at the student model and the error response is the same.

Comment: In Devise the column for database authenticable is called `encrypted_password`. Thats not a very good guide if you are planing on using Devise. Since Devise builds on Warden you want to create a warden authentication strategy for token based authentication instead of reinventing the wheel and creating something that won't integrate. https://729solutions.com/how-to-create-a-custom-strategy-with-the-devise-gem/

Comment: If you are just creating a API only application I would question if you really want to use Devise though. Its pretty bloated with features for classical web applications. I would go with Knock instead which is a much lighter JWT token authentication solution.

Comment: Chose one, use ActiveModel::HasSecurePassword (that's where `has_secure_password` `password_digest` and that `authenticate(password)` method comes from) or use Devise authentication. If I were to use devise then I would look for a tutorial that actually uses devise for authentication.

Comment: In fact my final objective is to develop a token based authentication API that will allow verified/registered users of my webapp request/download content from the webapp to a mobile app that will be developed. Currently my webapp uses Devise for authenticating users access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. If you are using devise and want to follow the tutorial below, forget about "gem 'bcrypt'" part and everything related to it (Including has_secure_password method).

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api

Finally at commands/authenticate_student.rb (I have changed user by student, in my case) substitute the line:

```
return student if student && student.authenticate(password)
```

by:

```
return student if student && student.valid_password?(password)
```

valid_password? is a devise method and will do the same work as authenticate.

That is it !